# How do you present a VC from Xib in Swift?

Tags: swift, segue, xib

I am trying to present a `VC` from a `Xib` file but it's resulting in

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBAction func viewCartBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let cart = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartVC") as? CartVC

        present(cart!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Check your outlets are properly connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code, YourStoryBoradName should be the name of storyboard without ".storyboard" extension :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoradName", bundle:nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartVC")as! CartVC
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```